# Delete line containing one of multiple strings

Tags: bash, text, sed

I have a text file and I want to remove all lines containing the words: `facebook`, `youtube`, `google`, `amazon`, `dropbox`, etc.

I know to delete lines containing a string with sed:

```
sed '/facebook/d' myfile.txt
```

I don't want to run this command five different times though for each string, is there a way to combine all the strings into one command?

Comment: Urgh so many high up on google questions like this where all the answers assume a short list. His list finishes with etc, are any of the answer's below reasonable if that blacklist is 100,000 words long?

Answer (score 16):

Try this:

```
sed '/facebook\|youtube\|google\|amazon\|dropbox/d' myfile.txt
```

From [GNU's sed manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html):

> `regexp1\|regexp2`
>
> Matches either *`regexp1`* or *`regexp2`*. Use parentheses to use
>   complex alternative regular expressions. The matching process tries
>   each alternative in turn, from left to right, and the first one that
>   succeeds is used. It is a GNU extension.

Answer (score 8):

```
grep -vf wordsToExcludeFile myfile.txt
```

"wordsToExcludeFile" should contain the words you don't want, one per line.

If you need to save the result back to the same file, then add this to the command:

```
 > myfile.new && mv myfile.new myfile.txt
```

Comment: dot is a regular expression "wildcard" character: dot matches any one character. The regex "facebook.com" will match the string "facebook-com", but it will also match the string "facebook.com". That's a long-winded of saying, yes it will work. Did you see unexpected results?

Answer (score 6):

With `awk`

```
awk '!/facebook|youtube|google|amazon|dropbox/' myfile.txt > filtered.txt
```

Comment: And with gawk I could exact match whole words only. "gawk '!/\<facebook\>|\<youtube\>|\<google\>|\<amazon\>|\<dropbox\>/' myfile.txt > filtered.txt"