# How to delete line that doesn't contain pattern 1 or pattern 2

Tags: sed, bsd

Using sed I can do this

```
sed -i '' '/myPattern/!d' file
```

But how can I make it compare against 2 patterns? So it only deletes lines that do not have at least 1 of the 2 patters?

Comment: I'd think a version of `grep` would be much better suited since you're operating on lines, something like `grep -v 'pattern1|pattern2' file`.  Depending on your version of `grep` or what your patterns are, you might have to use `egrep`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete line containing one of multiple strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17049962/3266847)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use multiple commands with `-e` and use `-n` and `p` instead of `!d`:

```
sed -n -i '' -e '/myPattern/p' -e '/myPattern2/p' file
```

Usually I prefer awk for that task since you can use boolean logic, like:

```
awk '/pattern1/ || /pattern2/' file
```

or

```
awk '/pattern1/ && /pattern2/' file
```

and so on.

---

Btw, having GNU awk you can also edit files in place:

```
gawk -i inplace '/pattern1/||/pattern2/' file
```

Comment: Thanks it looks to be doing exactly what I wanted. Is there any way I can make it not case sensitive?

Comment: I should add, other than this way [Pp][Aa][Tt][Tt][Ee][Rr][Nn]

Comment: GNU `awk`'s "inplace" is really "make a hidden temp file, then rename it over the old file".  [Per the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Extension-Sample-Inplace.html): "For each regular file that is processed, the extension redirects standard output to a temporary file configured to have the same owner and permissions as the original. After the file has been processed, the extension restores standard output to its original destination. ..."  So if you're space-constrained, for example, it won't help work around making a temp copy.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Well that's true for sed as well.

Comment: @Chris You have two options. Use `tolower()`, like this: `awk '{line=tolower($0)} line ~ /pattern1/ && line ~ /pattern2/' file` or, if you have GNU awk, you can set `IGNORECASE = 1`

Comment: @hek2mgl Yep. Won't work, but on a readonly filesystem even a true inplace edit would fail. The real problem with a pseudo-"inplace" option is that if you don't read the documentation closely you'd likely think it enables  processing an 8GB file on a filesystem with only 2GB free.

Comment: Thanks. Was just out of curiosity with the case thing.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I agree that using `sed -i` on a readonly fs system was a very bad example ;). You are right that one should always keep in mind that it is a *pseudo* inplace editing. Most likely you'll realize that when you get a disk full error.. :)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job for `grep`, e.g.:

```
seq 10 | grep -e 3 -e 7
```

Output:

```
3
7
```

Comment: I generally agree with that when the use case is *one out of* the patterns should match. I like to use `awk` because you can also specify logical *and* conditions or even more complex logic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

Delete any line not containing alpha or beta or gama.

```
sed -n '/alpha\|beta\|gama/p' < 1.txt > 2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd go with a case-insensitive (`-i`) negative (`-v`) `grep` for an extended (`-E`) alternation (`|`) of two patterns:

```
grep -viE `pattern1|pattern2' someFile
```