# For loop with sed to delete lines containing a list of letters

Tags: sed

I have a file cleansec_jobarray.sh

```
readCleaner -fastqdir /users/mfariasv/data/mfariasv/secrun/RSFV1F -outdir /users/mfariasv/data/mfariasv/secrun_clean/RSFV1F -contam /users/mfariasv/data/mfariasv/contams/contams.fa -trimjar /users/mfariasv/data/mfariasv/install/Trimmomatic-0.36/trimmomatic-0.36.jar -pe 1 -nthreads 4
readCleaner -fastqdir /users/mfariasv/data/mfariasv/secrun/RSFV1G -outdir /users/mfariasv/data/mfariasv/secrun_clean/RSFV1G -contam /users/mfariasv/data/mfariasv/contams/contams.fa -trimjar /users/mfariasv/data/mfariasv/install/Trimmomatic-0.36/trimmomatic-0.36.jar -pe 1 -nthreads 4
readCleaner -fastqdir /users/mfariasv/data/mfariasv/secrun/RSFV1H -outdir /users/mfariasv/data/mfariasv/secrun_clean/RSFV1H -contam /users/mfariasv/data/mfariasv/contams/contams.fa -trimjar /users/mfariasv/data/mfariasv/install/Trimmomatic-0.36/trimmomatic-0.36.jar -pe 1 -nthreads 4
readCleaner -fastqdir /users/mfariasv/data/mfariasv/secrun/RSFV1I -outdir /users/mfariasv/data/mfariasv/secrun_clean/RSFV1I -contam /users/mfariasv/data/mfariasv/contams/contams.fa -trimjar /users/mfariasv/data/mfariasv/install/Trimmomatic-0.36/trimmomatic-0.36.jar -pe 1 -nthreads 4
readCleaner -fastqdir /users/mfariasv/data/mfariasv/secrun/RSFV1J -outdir /users/mfariasv/data/mfariasv/secrun_clean/RSFV1J -contam /users/mfariasv/data/mfariasv/contams/contams.fa -trimjar /users/mfariasv/data/mfariasv/install/Trimmomatic-0.36/trimmomatic-0.36.jar -pe 1 -nthreads 4
readCleaner -fastqdir /users/mfariasv/data/mfariasv/secrun/RSFV1L -outdir /users/mfariasv/data/mfariasv/secrun_clean/RSFV1L -contam /users/mfariasv/data/mfariasv/contams/contams.fa -trimjar /users/mfariasv/data/mfariasv/install/Trimmomatic-0.36/trimmomatic-0.36.jar -pe 1 -nthreads 4
readCleaner -fastqdir /users/mfariasv/data/mfariasv/secrun/RSFV1M -outdir /users/mfariasv/data/mfariasv/secrun_clean/RSFV1M -contam /users/mfariasv/data/mfariasv/contams/contams.fa -trimjar /users/mfariasv/data/mfariasv/install/Trimmomatic-0.36/trimmomatic-0.36.jar -pe 1 -nthreads 4
readCleaner -fastqdir /users/mfariasv/data/mfariasv/secrun/RSFV1N -outdir /users/mfariasv/data/mfariasv/secrun_clean/RSFV1N -contam /users/mfariasv/data/mfariasv/contams/contams.fa -trimjar /users/mfariasv/data/mfariasv/install/Trimmomatic-0.36/trimmomatic-0.36.jar -pe 1 -nthreads 4
readCleaner -fastqdir /users/mfariasv/data/mfariasv/secrun/RSFV1O -outdir /users/mfariasv/data/mfariasv/secrun_clean/RSFV1O -contam /users/mfariasv/data/mfariasv/contams/contams.fa -trimjar /users/mfariasv/data/mfariasv/install/Trimmomatic-0.36/trimmomatic-0.36.jar -pe 1 -nthreads 4
readCleaner -fastqdir /users/mfariasv/data/mfariasv/secrun/RSFV1P -outdir /users/mfariasv/data/mfariasv/secrun_clean/RSFV1P -contam /users/mfariasv/data/mfariasv/contams/contams.fa -trimjar /users/mfariasv/data/mfariasv/install/Trimmomatic-0.36/trimmomatic-0.36.jar -pe 1 -nthreads 4
```

I want to delete lines containing RSFV1F, RSFV1M, RSFV1O

I know It can be done using
[Delete line containing one of multiple strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049962/delete-line-containing-one-of-multiple-strings)
or
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/400860/loop-sed-to-delete-line-with-strings-provided-in-a-list-of-strings-from-a-text-f

But I want to do using a loop with sed

I've tried

```
for f in F M O; do sed "/RSFV1$f/d" cleansec_jobarray.sh; done
```

But no chance

Comment: No, you do not want to do it using a loop with sed as that would be an anti-pattern. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/RSFV1[FMO]/d' file
```

or:

```
grep -v 'RSFV1[FMO]' file
```

Answer (score -1):

Oh my... Just add -i and should work!

```
for f in F M O; do sed -i "/RSFV1$f/d" cleansec_jobarray.sh; done
```

Comment: Interestingly if you try using this reverting the selection, as in for f in F M O; do sed -i "/RSFV1$f/!d" cleansec_jobarray.sh; done, it wont work. Don't know why.

Comment: `-i` saves the changes made. So when processing in a loop: the first round deletes every line not matching the first pattern (i.e. it leaves only the lines containing `RSFV1F`) & saves those changes. The second time round the loop it would delete every line not matching `RSFV1M` & saves changes (which produces an empty file!). Could use (without loop) `sed '/RSFV1[FMO]/!d' file`.